Does cycling a main electrical breaker result in a power surge?
Would turning off main electrical breaker switch in the breaker box on & off really fast cause a power surge and cause damage to something like an internet router?
When turning off the main electrical breaker switch how long should I wait to turn it back on?

Welcome. Please see the [help] and take the [tour]. You'll notice that I reduced your question to something on topic for this site.

Using the main breaker should not cause any surges. However, that breaker is not designed for frequent use. It is meant for use when working on the panel and for emergencies such as damage to the panel, fire or flooding or other ongoing damage to the building or turning off (combined with an interlock) in order to turn on a generator.
Your options include:

Unplug the router. It is unusual for a consumer level router to be hardwired.
Turn off the circuit breaker for the circuit powering the router. In the US 15A and 20A breakers are normally switch rated which makes it safe and reliable to turn them off/on on a daily basis.
Reset through a connected device. Most routers have a web interface that includes reset capability.


Even when not used much, the main breaker can break/not turn on again.  Found that out when a electrician working on the wiring ask me to turn the main back on.  You do not know how glad I had an electrician on site when that happen, power on again in half an hour.

The breaker action would not cause a surge.
However, interrupting power to a motor could cause a surge to be generated by your own equipment.   First, you have the inductive "kick" generated by any inductive load when it is interrupted.  That's why old magnetic ballast fluorescents and HID (metal vapor lights) need special HID breakers if you turn them on/off at the breaker.
Also, interrupting power for a very short time can cause a weird thing to happen with motors. When you cut power, the motor is being decelerated by the load and is "spinning down". If you snap power back on during this spin-down, on some motors it can catch the motor out of phase with the power. This can result in a considerable mechanical and electrical kick, comparable to connecting two generators out of sync.  Practical Engineering on Youtube has a demonstration rig where he does that and the whole table shakes. The electrical kick would be impressive as well.
So yeah, the breaker isn't making a spike, but other loads in the house very well could.


Would turning off main electrical breaker switch in the breaker box on & off really fast cause a power surge and cause damage to something like an internet router?

No, not a surge.
Yes, it could cause damage.  Computer equipment is not made for fast cycling.  As an example, this could cause the heads to crash in a hard drive.  In a router, I would worry that it might damage something like flash memory or the power supply.
When disconnecting a router, I would wait twenty seconds before plugging it back into the outlet.  If you are disconnecting via the circuit breaker, that still holds.  Note:  problems will be infrequent.  You can do this a number of times with no issue.  Then one day, you try it and something fizzles.
If your goal is to reset the router, then I wouldn't use the circuit breaker.  You could probably get better advice around something like that on SuperUser.
My recommendation is that if you want to cycle the circuit breaker multiple times, that you turn off and unplug any computer equipment before you start.


Would turning off main electrical breaker switch in the breaker box on & off really fast cause a power surge and cause damage?

No.

When turning off the main electrical breaker switch how long should I wait to turn it back on?

The main disconnect is used for servicing the electrical system.  It should remain off until the electrical system is properly installed with no loose wires.
